# c++ receives segfault through GDB but not xCode -- need help debugging

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a project and have recently started running into a particularly nasty segfault. Here is some background:

1 -- I have a queue of "orders" on which I have tested the following:
a -- filling up (0 orders, 1 order, and many orders), removed until isEmpty() returns true, and filled other queues with these results (this replicates the programs behavior)

2 -- found this from gdb:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/Nicholas M. Iodice/Dropbox/tufts/noz2/noz2/a.out 
Reading symbols for shared libraries ++......................... done
order added 1

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x0000000100003a66 in Queue::remove (this=0x7fff5fbffaa0) at Queue.cpp:85
85      ElementType retVal = front->order;
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000000100003a66 in Queue::remove (this=0x7fff5fbffaa0) at Queue.cpp:85
#1  0x0000000100002c08 in Packer::packItem (this=0x7fff5fbffaa0, time=1) at Packer.cpp:88
#2  0x0000000100002e3f in Packer::update (this=0x7fff5fbffaa0, time=1) at Packer.cpp:131
#3  0x0000000100002e9c in PackerManager::update (this=0x7fff5fbffaa0, i=1) at Packer.cpp:295
#4  0x0000000100001ffa in Manager::run (this=0x7fff5fbff830, careAboutSupreme=false) at Manager.cpp:126
#5  0x000000010000511a in main (argc=0, argv=0x7fff5fbffb48) at main.cpp:173
(gdb)
```

the "order added 1" is some logging I've added in, and it occurs when my "Fetcher" class sends an order to the "PackerManager" class, which determines which "Packer" object to add an order to. I modified my code so that all orders are routed through ONE "Packer" object, for debugging purposes.

3 -- This means that when the "Packer" object calls packItem (which will call remove() from my Queue, there is just one order in that queue. I have tested this outside of these classes, and it works fine.

1. Here is some relevant code:

from "Queue"

```
Queue::Queue()
{
    front = NULL;
    back = NULL;

    //head = NULL;
    //tail = NULL;
    count = 0;
}

//instert to back of queue
void Queue::insert(ElementType order)
{
    if(isEmpty()){
        back = new Node;
        back->order = order;
        back->next = NULL;
        front = back;
    }else{
        Node* tmp = new Node;
        tmp->order = order;
        back->next = tmp;
        back = back->next;
        back->next = NULL;
    }
    count++;
}

//checks if head & tail = NULL
bool Queue::isEmpty()
{
    if(front == NULL && back == NULL){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

throws segfault on this line: "ElementType retVal = front->order;"

```
ElementType Queue::remove()
{
    if(isEmpty()){
        cout << "\n\tYou cannot remove from an empty Queue... Exiting.\n\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    ElementType retVal = front->order;
    //delete front;
    if(front == back){
        front = NULL;
        back = NULL;
    }else{
        front = front->next;
    }

    count --;
    return retVal;
}
```

this code calls remove from the queue. The one it is calling is "regularOrders"

```
//retreives next order to begin packing
void Packer::packItem(int time)
{
    if( careAboutSupreme && !supremeOrders.isEmpty() ){
        orderBeingPacked = supremeOrders.remove();
        orderBeingPackedStartTime = time;

    }else if( careAboutSupreme && isDelayOrderWaiting ){
        orderBeingPacked = orderBeingDelayed;
        orderBeingPackedStartTime = orderBeingDelayedStart + delayDuration;
        delayDuration = 0;
        isDelayOrderWaiting = false;

    }else if( !regularOrders.isEmpty() ){
        orderBeingPacked = regularOrders.remove();
        orderBeingPackedStartTime = time;
    }
}
```

Also, the queue passes this test with values i = 1 and i > 1:

```
#if Q
    Queue q1;
    Queue q2;
    for(int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){
        Order o;
        q1.insert(o);
    }

    while(!q1.isEmpty()){
        q2.insert(q1.remove());
    }

    sortQueueByOrderNumber(q2);

    while(!q2.isEmpty()){
        q2.remove();
    }
    cout << "Expecting to exit now" << endl;
    q2.remove();
#endif

void sortQueueByOrderNumber(Queue q)
{
    if(q.getCount() == 0){
        return;
    }
    int cnt = q.getCount();
    Order* orderArray = new Order[cnt];
    Order tmpOrder;

    //put orders into array -- after this they are in order, but in an array
    while(q.getCount() != 0){
        tmpOrder = q.remove();
        orderArray[tmpOrder.orderNum-1] = tmpOrder;
    }

    //now we stuff em back into the queue, in order!
    for(int i=0 ; i<cnt ; i++){
        tmpOrder = orderArray[i];
        q.insert(tmpOrder);
    }
    delete[] orderArray;
}
```

Please let me know what else I can provide.

EDIT:
It looks like a null pointer isnt the issue here: I tried adding this:

```
ElementType retVal;
if(front == NULL){
    cout <<"oops!";
}else{
    retVal = front->order;
}
```

The code still falls into assigning retVal = front->order. So front != NULL, however, it thinks that front->order is a bad memory location.

**EDIT 2:**
ok, this is weird. when compiling with clang++ it actually works (sorry if i stated otherwise earlier), just not g++. WHAT?

**EDIT 3**
Ok, so I have scp'd these files to another machine and tried to run it. Now I am getting segmentation faults with both g++ and clang++, however, in a completley different area unrelated to the queue at all.

Is there something else I should be looking at that could cause a more widespread memory issue?

The segfault now occurs when trying to update one of the packer objects. The code is below, and it fails updating the time (this->time = time) -- I dont think this should happen, which is why I'm thinking there may be a larger issue at hand. Also, i checked with GDB, but this->time is not NULL.

```
void Packer::update(int time)
{
    this->time = time;

    //if orderNum = 0 we havent gotten a real order yet. This is the default from the constructor for Order
    if(orderBeingPacked.orderNum == 0){
        packItem(time);
    }
```

Comment: Make up a simple test case where you add and remove elements. Then post a minimal one that fails (segfaults) and post it, if that doesn't help you enough already.

Comment: Hi Christian, thank you for your comment. I added some test cases above, but these all pass.

Comment: have you considered using [std::queue<ElementType>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/) instead of your own Queue implementation ?

Comment: Unfortunately this is an assignment, the point of which is to learn how to implement a queue.

Comment: can you guarantee that `orderNum` is in the range 0..(total number of orders -1) ?

Comment: Yes, the order number is generated from an input text file. I know for sure that order numbers range from 1 - someNumberBiggerThanOne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isEmpty()` returning false does **not** guarantee that `front` is not `NULL`.

Put asserts in `isEmpty()` like:

```
bool Queue::isEmpty()
{
    if(front == NULL || back == NULL){
        assert(front == NULL);
        assert(back == NULL);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, do you initialize both `front` and `back` to `NULL` in the constructor ?

---

**EDIT:**
Another thing to check is whether your order numbers do not exceed the temporary array in `sortQueueByOrderNumber`:

```
void sortQueueByOrderNumber(Queue q)
{
    ...
    int cnt = q.getCount();
    Order* orderArray = new Order[cnt];
    Order tmpOrder;

    //put orders into array -- after this they are in order, but in an array
    while(q.getCount() != 0){
        tmpOrder = q.remove();

        assert(tmpOrder.orderNum >= 1);       // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        assert(tmpOrder.orderNum-1 < cnt);    // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

        orderArray[tmpOrder.orderNum-1] = tmpOrder;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

**EDIT2:** Another potential pitfall: make sure you implement an assignment operator and a copy constructor where you copy the queue structure:

```
Queue::Queue(const Queue &other) :
  front(NULL),
  back(NULL),
  count(0)
{
  Node *node = other.front;
  while (node != NULL)
  {
    insert(node->order);
    node = node->next;
  }
}
```

Otherwise, e.g. when calling `sortQueueByOrderNumber(Queue q)` (assuming you haven't made it a refernce as Maciek B points out) you'll share (because of the wait the default copy constructor works) the queue nodes between multiple Queue instances or worse you'll call delete on all nodes on one object going out of scope (e.g. at the end of `sortQueueByOrderNumber`) while another `Queue` instance still points to the (deleted) `Node` objects.

Comment: Andre, thank you for this. You can see from the constructor (I just added this) that both pointers are initialized. The assertion comes back as failed: Assertion failed: (front == NULL), function isEmpty, file Queue.cpp, line 32. Looking into assertions now (these are new to me)

Comment: so you seem to have a situation where `back != NULL` but `front == NULL`

Comment: Two things -- 1) i only see this when running in GDB, not from a simple "./a.out" in terminal, and 2) My understanding after reading online is that this will only fail if front != null, at least from reading here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/

Comment: as far as I understood from your code must `front` and `back` either be both be NULL or both be non-NULL. So assertions basically make sure that conditions you know must hold actually are satisfied when the program runs.

If you only experience this problem in gdb, you may be affected by [memory corruption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption) and you may want to run the program with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) which is available e.g. on Macports, however, this can take a long time and much more memory to run the program.

Comment: There is one case, where only one item is in the queue, where front = back. Other than that, both are non-NULL or both are NULL. This only occurs when compiling with g++/clang++ and running from the terminal. It runs in xcode just fine.

Comment: The assertion in sortQueueByOrderNumber passes fine :/

Comment: Andre, the copy constructor solved this problem! Thank you very very much! Now I'm segfaulting on accessing a private data member, however, that is outside of the scope of this problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Is this delete commented out?

```
ElementType retVal = front->order;
//delete front;
if(front == back){
    front = NULL;
    back = NULL;
}else{
    front = front->next;
}
```

you shouldn't delete `front` and then use `front->next`. Try this instead:

```
ElementType retVal = front->order;
Node* x = front;
if(front == back){
    front = NULL;
    back = NULL;
}else{
    front = front->next;
}
delete x;
```

**EDIT:**

Also method `sortQueueByOrderNumber` takes `Queue` parameter by value so any changes of `front` and `back` will not be stored in original `Queue` object. Change the signature to:

`void sortQueueByOrderNumber(Queue& q)`

If you still have problems then use `valgrind`. It should find those memory issues or at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you Maciek B, the delete was commented out for that reason, but i think this is a good change for the code anyways. Much appreciated!